# ¿Cómo copiar un archivo PDF a partir de su uri?

Tags: android, archivo, kotlin, pdf, guardar

Estoy tratando de seleccionar un pdf y luego copiarlo a otra ubicación. He hecho lo mismo con imagenes y si me sale.

Les dejo el código de la imagen seleccionada de cualquier parte del celular. Lo que hace es obtener la uri y con esa uri `contentResolver.openInputStream(imageUri)` generar un `InputStream` y sobre ese `InputStream` convertitlo en un `Bitmap` y crear un file `ByteArrayOutputStream(`) escribir en ese file creado y guardarlo en la ubicacion `getExternalFilesDir("images")/nombreimagen.jpg`

Este es el codigo que lanza la actividad

```
selectImage.launch("image/*")
```

Este es el codigo del registerForActivityResult

```
val selectImage = registerForActivityResult(
        ActivityResultContracts.GetContent(),
        ActivityResultCallback {imageUri ->
            val storageDirImages: File = getExternalFilesDir("images")!!
            val ims = contentResolver.openInputStream(imageUri)
            val filename = imageUri.path?.substringAfterLast("/")
            val bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(ims)
            val tipo = filename?.substringAfterLast(".")
            var f: File ?= null
            if(tipo.equals("jpg")) {
                f = File("${storageDirImages}" +
                        File.separator + filename)
            }else if(tipo.equals("png")) {
                f = File("${storageDirImages}" +
                        File.separator + filename)
            }else {
                f = File("${storageDirImages}" +
                        File.separator + filename + ".jpg")
            }

            f?.createNewFile()

            val bos = ByteArrayOutputStream()
            if(tipo.equals("jpg")) {
                bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100 , bos);
            }else if(tipo.equals("png")) {
                bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 0, bos);
            }else{
                bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100 , bos);
            }

            val bitmapdata: ByteArray = bos.toByteArray()
            val fos = FileOutputStream(f)
            fos.write(bitmapdata)
            fos.flush()
            fos.close()
        }
    )
```

Con el pdf lanzo la actividad

```
selectPdf.launch("application/pdf")
```

Y luego hago esto con la uri trate de convertirlo a bitmap pero me dio nulo pero logre almacenarlo con PdfRenderer pero ahi nomas me quede el codigo comentado fue un intento fallido de convertir la uri en bitmap no pude.

```
val selectPdf = registerForActivityResult(
        ActivityResultContracts.GetContent(),
        ActivityResultCallback {uriPdf ->
            Log.i("uriPdf", "${uriPdf}")
            Log.i("uriPdf", "${uriPdf.path}")
            val storageDirPdf: File = getExternalFilesDir("pdf")!!
            val filename = uriPdf.path?.substringAfterLast("/")
            val contador = countOccurrences(filename!!, '.')
            Log.i("contador", "${contador}")
            if(contador == 0){
                //val ims = contentResolver.openInputStream(uriPdf)
                val fileDescriptor: ParcelFileDescriptor =
                    contentResolver.openFileDescriptor(uriPdf, "r")!!

                val renderer = PdfRenderer(fileDescriptor)
                renderer.openPage(1)
                /*var bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(ims)
                lateinit var pdfDocument: PdfDocument
                val pi =
                    PdfDocument.PageInfo.Builder(bitmap.getWidth(),bitmap.getHeight(), 1)
                        .create()
                val page = pdfDocument.startPage(pi)
                val canvas: Canvas = page.canvas
                lateinit var paint: Paint
                paint.color = Color.parseColor("#FFFFFF")
                canvas.drawPaint(paint)
                bitmap = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(bitmap, bitmap.width, bitmap.height, true)
                paint.color = Color.BLUE
                canvas.drawBitmap(bitmap, 0.0F, 0.0F, null)
                pdfDocument.finishPage(page)
                var f: File ?= File("${storageDirPdf}" +
                        File.separator + filename + ".pdf")
                f?.createNewFile()

                try{
                    val fileOutputStream = FileOutputStream(f)
                    pdfDocument.writeTo(fileOutputStream)
                }catch (e: Exception){
                    e.printStackTrace()
                }*/
            }else{

            }
            /*if(tipo.equals("pdf")){
                Toast.makeText(applicationContext, "PDF", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
            }else{
                Toast.makeText(applicationContext, "Archivo no permitido", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
            }*/
        })
```

He investigado y he encontrado como convertir una sola pagina del pdf a bitmap pero lo que necesito es que **todo el pdf** se guarde como file no solo una página.

Espero que me puedan ayudar

Comment: La pregunta no es clara. Cómo que quieres convertir un pdf en pdf? Quieres duplicar el archivo o modificarlo? Y para qué necesitas un bitmap?

Comment: Sí, quiero duplicarlo he tratado de obtener la ruta absoluta pero no he podido para despues convertirlo en un file. El bitmap lo necesitaba para poder hacer una réplica de la imagen pero creo que se puede utilizar tambien para el pdf var bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(ims) en esta línea no se puede decodificar el inputstream sale null.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Dado que todos los archivos se almacenan como bytes, copiar un archivo PDF es lo mismo que copiar cualquier otro archivo. Todo lo que tienes que hacer es leer esos bytes y escribirlos en la ubicación deseada.

El problema con tu código es que añades pasos innecesarios como decodificar el archivo, volver a codificarlo, renderizar el PDF, etc, que no hacen más que ralentizar el proceso.

Si eliminas esos pasos puedes tener una sola función que copie cualquier tipo de archivo. Es decir que todo tu código se podría refactorizar así

```
val selectFile = registerForActivityResult(ActivityResultContracts.GetContent()) { uri ->
    val file = DocumentFile.fromSingleUri(this,uri)!!
    val fileName = file.name!!
    val fileType = file.type!!
    val dirName = when {
        fileType.startsWith("image") -> "images"
        fileType == "application/pdf" -> "pdf"
        else -> return@registerForActivityResult Toast
            .makeText(this, "Archivo no permitido", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
            .show()
    }
    contentResolver.openInputStream(uri)?.use { input ->
        val output = File(getExternalFilesDir(dirName), fileName).outputStream()
        input.copyTo(output)
        output.close()
    }
}
```

Y luego le pasas como argumento el tipo de archivo que quieras selecionar, por ejemplo `selectFile.launch("application/pdf")` o `selectFile.launch("image/*")`.

Comment: Debes crear otra pegunta para ese problema